# Viewing Core Data data from your app on a device

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift3, ios10

I am building an app but testing it on my iPhone. The app is plugged into my computer and running from XCode. Is there anyway to see the data in Core Data that the app has generated? I see all the posts about the simulator and the files generated. I am trying to use DB Browser too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Step1:**

Plug your device and open Devices and Simulators:

[image]

**Step 2:**

Select your app from installed Apps:

[image]

**Step 3:**

Press the settings icon and download container

[image]

**Step 4:**

Select the downloaded .xcappdata and show package contents:

[image]

**Step 5:**

Find the .sqlite file inside and open it using any sqlite reader like [DB Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org)

[image]